# XamarinForm DataTemplate ListView Binding

Tags: data-binding, xamarin.forms, custom-controls, datatemplate

I want to bind to a variable from inside a CustomControl referenced in a ListView DataTemplate

This is the situation:
I have a custom control containing a ListView with many DataTemplates to display the various ViewCell (it's basically a set of dynamic fields that must be displayed according to their "type").

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:s4gvForms="clr-namespace:S4GVMobile.Forms;assembly=S4GVMobile"
         xmlns:s4gvControls="clr-namespace:S4GVMobile.Controls;assembly=S4GVMobile"
         x:Class="S4GVMobile.Controls.AttributesList"
         x:Name="S4GVAttributesListControl"
         >
<ContentView.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <!-- MANY DATA TEMPLATES HERE, ONLY ONE LEFT FOR REFERENCE -->
        <DataTemplate x:Key="s4gvAttributePictureTemplate">
            <ViewCell x:Name="s4gvAttributePictureViewCell">
                <ViewCell.View>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Attribute.Key}" />
                        <s4gvControls:AttributePicture ParentID="{Binding Source={x:Reference s4gvAttributePictureViewCell}, Path=Parent.BindingContext.EntityID}" AttributeValue="{Binding .}"  />
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell.View>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
        <!-- ... -->
        <!-- AGAIN, LONG LIST IN THE SELECTOR -->
        <s4gvForms:AttributeDataTemplateSelector x:Key="s4gvAttributeDataTemplateSelector"
                                                 AttributePictureTemplate="{StaticResource s4gvAttributePictureTemplate}"
                                                 />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentView.Resources>
<StackLayout>
    <ListView x:Name="s4gvAttributes" HasUnevenRows="True" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource s4gvAttributeDataTemplateSelector}" ItemsSource="{Binding AttributeValues}" />
</StackLayout>
```

I'm passing to this custom control both the list of items (required by the ListView) and an additional EntityID.

```
<s4gv:AttributesList x:Name="s4gvSerialAttributes" AttributeValues="{Binding Serial.AttributeValues}" EntityID="{Binding Serial.SerialID}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
```

The custom control has the required bindable properties (AttibuteValues and EntityID) and relies on a dedicated ViewModel

I need to retrieve the EntityID from inside the DataTemplate (and put it in the ParentID property); this value is in the custom control's ViewModel but it is "outside" the ListView's DataTemplates. I've tried using the Parent.BindingContext (it works on Command and CommandParameter) but it seems that it can only go up to the ListView's context and not higher though I need to move one further step up to the CustomControl itself.

```
<s4gvControls:AttributePicture ParentID="{Binding Source={x:Reference s4gvAttributePictureViewCell}, Path=Parent.BindingContext.EntityID}" AttributeValue="{Binding .}"  />
```

Any idea? I'm happy to restructure the whole thing if required.

Comment: As a side note, I've resolved this the easy way: I have added the EntityID to a wrapper around each AttributeValue so that it is always available to each DataTemplate. I find it less "elegant" as the EntityID is passed to each element even when not required. I believe other environments (such as WPF) have a XAML RelativeSource element that would be useful in these situations.

Comment: As an additional side note (one month later), please be aware that the order of XAML attributes _does_ matter.